# Detect which Usercontrol on a Form has been clicked

Tags: c#, user-controls

What's my situation?
I'm using C#. I have a form with multiple instances of a single usercontrol. The usercontrol has three buttons. Add, Close and Select.

What am I trying to achieve?
I want to get the Tag of the user control instance, when its close button is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Usercontrol, add an eventhandler to the button. Within the Eventhandler fire an event, to which you add an eventhandler in your Form

Edit: Something like this
Edit2: Changed it to meet the posters requirements

```
public delegate void UControlButtonCloseClickedHandler(UControl sender, EventArgs e);
public partial class UControl : UserControl
{
    public event UControlButtonCloseClickedHandler UControlButtonCloseClicked;

    public UControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        btnAdd.Click += ButtonAdd_Click;
        btnSelect.Click += ButtonSelect_Click;
        btnClose.Click += ButtonClose_Click;
    }


    private void ButtonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UControlButtonCloseClicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

And in your Form then just add a handler like `uControl.UControlButtonCloseClicked += Hanlder;`

Answer (score -1):

Why not link each button to the same event and then get the name of the control to determine if it is the close button (as each control MUST have a unique name, unless you're dynamically adding controls to the form but even at that you should be assigning a name). EDIT: And by getting the name I actually mean comparing if the control that triggered the event is the same one that you want to perform the close action, open action, etc. :)

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnCloseButton.Click += new EventHandler(OnUserControlClick);
        btnOtherRandomButton.Click += new EventHandler(OnUserControlClick);
        btnOtherRandomButton1.Click += new EventHandler(OnUserControlClick);
    }

    private static void OnUserControlClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender as UserControl == btnCloseButton)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not really sure the reason for the down vote as it answers the question with a sample and explanation. Poor conduct...